# Pourquoi « rendre » signifie 'represent, depict'?

Tags: étymologie

En Ancien Français, comme en Latin,  rendre = '**give back**'. Mais dès 1500s, [the meaning `"represent, depict"` is attested from 1590s"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/render?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_10422).

Comment '**give back**' se rapporte à `"represent, depict"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the etymological notes (“Étymol. et Hist.”) in the [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rendre), the verb acquired many nuances in its concrete meaning in Old French:

- A. « Donner en retour (une chose reçue ou prise, son équivalent, ou ce qui est dû) » (give back something that was received or taken, or its equivalent, or what is due)

  - (1.) « donner à nouveau » (give again)
  - (2.) « donner quelque chose de semblable » (give something similar)
  - (3.) « donner en retour ce qui est dû » (give back what is owed)
  - (4.) « produire, rapporter » (produce, yield — e.g. the land giving back a food crop)
  - (5.) « donner à nouveau » (give again)

From there, several other meanings arose, including:

- B. « Laisser échapper, redonner ce qu'on ne peut garder, céder, livrer » (let something escape, give back what one cannot keep, relinquish, deliver) — thus “*se rendre*” (surrender), “*rendre*” (vomit), etc.
- C. Causing something to return to a past state, evolving into into causing something to change state
- D. « Remettre à destination » (send back to its destination), evolving into going somewhere you haven't been before
- E. Domaine intellectuel ou esthét. « présenter (après interprétation) » (intellectual or aesthetic domain: present upon interpretation, represent)

  - (1.a) 1549 (Du Bellay, Deffense et Illustration, éd. H. Chamard, p. 160: « je veux aussi que tu t'eforces de rendre […] la phrase et maniere de parler Latine »; modern spelling: « je veux aussi que tu t'efforces de rendre la phrase et la manière de parler Latine »; “I want you to strive to give back/convey the Latin sentence [structure] and manner of speech”)
  - (1.b) 1579 « rendu mot pour mot » (en traduction) (H. Estienne, Precellence, éd. E. Huguet, p. 41) (give back word for word, in translation)
  - (2.a) 1733 (Dubos, Réflexions crit., t. 1, p. 81: « Ce que Cornelie dit à César [...] ne peut être rendu par un peintre » (“what Cornelie tells Caesar (…) cannot be given back/depicted by a painter”); t. 3, p. 232: « Roscius rendoit donc par un jeu muet le sens de la phrase que Ciceron venoit de composer »; modern spelling: « Roscius rend donc par un jeu muet le sens de la phrase que Cicéron vient de composer » (“Roscius gives back/expresses through silent play/motion the meaning of the sentence that Cicero just composed”))
  - (2.b) 1740 (Ac. Add.: « Une glace qui rend nettement les objets » (a mirror that gives back/shows objects clearly))
  - (2.c) 1745 (Bosse, Manière de graver, p. 129: « On dirigera la gravûre de façon que le blanc du papier, comme on l'a dit, rende le luisans du tableau » (“One shall direct the etching in such manner that the white of the paper, as aforementioned, renders/depicts/gives back the shininess of the painting”))
  - (2.d) 1754 (Bonnet, Essai psychol., p. 146: « des couleurs mal rendues » (misrendered colors)).

So, generally, “give something back” evolved into “give something in return”, and then many secondary meanings evolved where the “in return” part became weak or tenuous. A similar phenomenon is possible in English: quite a few of the meanings can be translated by “give back”. Land “gives back” a crop, words “give back” the intent that the writer put in them, a painting “gives back” the colors put into it...